# Want to generate and return unique ID for each entry

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Kindly check and rectify this code

```
 Public Function RegisterToEventFAMLY(ByVal p As Participant, ByVal PartcName As String, ByVal Rel As String, ByVal DOB As String, ByVal EVT As String) As String
        Using con As New SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)
            Dim cmdEv As New SqlCommand("select 'TATA' + RIGHT('0000'+CAST(CHESTNO+1 as VARCHAR(4)),4) from (select top 1 CHESTNO=CAST(RIGHT(CHESTNO,4)as int ) from [SANDBOX].[dbo].[T_HTK_USR_DTLS] order by CHESTNO desc) t where Pno=@IDNo", con)
            cmdEv.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDNo", p.ID)

            Dim daEv As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdEv)
            Dim dtEv As New DataTable

            Try
                Dim newRowCreated = False
                daEv.Fill(dtEv)
                Dim drEv As DataRow
                If (dtEv.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                    drEv = dtEv.Rows(0)
                Else
                    drEv = dtEv.NewRow
                    newRowCreated = True
                End If


                drEv("Pno") = p.ID
                drEv("NAME") = PartcName ''---event code 
                drEv("BASE_LOCATION") = DOB
                drEv("EVENTNM") = Rel
                drEv("MAC_ID") = Rel

                If (newRowCreated) Then
                    dtEv.Rows.Add(drEv)
                End If
                Dim cmdbEv As New SqlCommandBuilder(daEv)
                cmdbEv.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges
                daEv.Update(dtEv)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ex.Message
            End Try
        End Using
        Return "True"
    End Function
```

Showing exception error

> Invalid Column name 'Pno'

Comment: Have you put the column into your `SELECT` statement? I know it's elsewhere but in order to use it you need to bring it into the `SELECT` part so that it's accessible. `SELECT Pno, column2, column3 etc from...`

Comment: @GurV ya you are right. Can you kindly rectify my query

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`select [pno], 'TATA' + RIGHT('0000'+CAST([CHESTNO]+1 as VARCHAR(4)),4) from 
  (select top 1 [CHESTNO]=CAST(RIGHT([CHESTNO],4) as int ) from 
    [SANDBOX].[dbo].[T_HTK_USR_DTLS] order by [CHESTNO] desc) t 
      where [Pno]=@IDNo`